# Trying to apply regex to column in select query

Tags: mysql, json, regex

I have JSON stored in a MySQL database (version 5.6.17) that I'm trying to regex into a column to retrieve a list of campaign IDs. My query is as follows:

```
SELECT JSON REGEXP '"id":([0-9]*)' AS id
FROM PROD_APPNEXUS.dimension_json_creatives;
```

where JSON is a column containing the data I need to parse as ID. I know REGEXP can be used for strings in SELECT queries (i.e. SELECT 'foobar' REGEXP '([a-z]+)' AS foobar) but can columns be pattern matched in the same way?

Would there be a way to cast the JSON column as string and then regex?

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks,

Sam

Comment: Did you try it? What was the result? Where did it differ from your expectation?

Comment: I've tried it, but the query returns a column of 1s for every row of JSON in the table. I'm expecting to retrieve IDs of variable length. I'm thinking perhaps you can transform the JSON column to string in SELECT and then parse the column by regex...

Comment: REGEXP only return 1 or 0 which means `true` or `false`.

Comment: So in my case, REGEXP would have successfully returned a match (by returning a column of 1s), I just need to find a way to output that as column?

Comment: @SamComber Anyway, you can try my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `replace` and `substring_index` to split your column, like this;)

```
SELECT replace(substring_index(JSON, ':', -1), '"', '') AS id
FROM PROD_APPNEXUS.dimension_json_creatives;
```

when I run sql below return *aaaa*,

```
select replace(substring_index('"id":"aaaa"', ':', -1), '"', '');
```

I assumed your JSON's value does not exist `:`.